# sql like statement picking up unexpected results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple table like the following

```
id, target
-----------
1, test_1
2, test_2
3, test_3
4, testable
```

I have a simple query like so:

```
select * from my_table where target like 'test_%'
```

What I'm expecting are the first 3 records but I'm getting all 4 records

See SQLFiddle [example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a49ed/1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Underscore is a pattern matching character. Try this:

```
select * from my_table where target like 'test[_]%'
```

Answer (score 6):

_ is also a wildcard. You can escape it like:

```
... like 'test\_%' escape '\'
```

Comment: never seen the escape keyword used before. I probably prefer steve's answer above, but +1 for being the person to teach me something new today.

Comment: escape is standard sql and will work with most DBMS. Don't forget to mark Steves answer as a solution if you find it to be the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

The underscore character _ as you've used it is a wildcard for a single character, hence it returns 4 rows.   Try using [_] instead of _.

To illustrate..

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (val varchar(10)) 

INSERT INTO #tmp (val)
VALUES ('test_1'), ('test_2'), ('test_3'), ('testing')

-- This returns all four
SELECT * FROM #tmp WHERE val LIKE 'test_%'

-- This returns the three test_ rows
SELECT * FROM #tmp WHERE val LIKE 'test[_]%'
```

Answer (score 3):

The underscore is a wildcard character that says "match any character single character", just like the % is a wildcard that says "match any 0 or more characters".  If you're familiar with Regular Expressions, the underscore character is equivalent to the dot there. You'll need to properly escape the underscore to match that character literally.